# How can I list module dependencies using yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

New to Yarn and js.

I'm trying to list the dependencies of an installed module using Yarn.

I used `yarn add jest` to install Jest and all it's dependencies.

Now I want to list Jest and all its dependencies.
How can I do this? 
I tried `yarn list jest`, but it only is listing Jest.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be simply to locate the package.json file in the relevant package's folder: `node_modules/packagename/package.json` - ignore 'devDependencies' as those are not installed when you pull in a package.